# Picture Tag Not Showing Image, Reads "Source 0x0"

Tags: html, image, responsive-design, responsive

My client has stressed that the images in their website are blurry so I am trying to fix this issue. Per my research one way is to create different sized images per device (small, med, large) using the `<picture>` tag. However, when using the developer tools, my images does not show up at all, in says `"Source 0x0."` What is also happening is when on mobile or on tablet devices the default image is always selected rather than the appropriate image. I have researched this problem and could not find an adequate answer for my case. I even tried to change my path, nothing. I am only using HTML for this part. Any help is appreciated.

Also, if anyone can recommend a more efficient way of making images more crisp and less blurry please point me in the right direction. I have heard of using SVG but I can't find solid advice on this method.

HTML

```
    <div class="view3">
        <div class="content5_items">
            <h1 class="text-center">Sign Up</h1>
            <br>
            <p class="text-center">Join Wanzeru Now</p>
            <br>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 d-flex justify-content-end">
                        <picture>
                             <source media="(max-width: 480px)" srcset="img/sign_upSmall.png">
                             <source media="(max-width: 768px)" srcset="img/sign_upMed.png">
                            <img src="img/sign_up.png" alt="pic"> <!--this image is only being applied -->
                        </picture>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 justify-content-md-start justify-content-center d-flex text-center" style="margin-top: 50px;">
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn" style="background-color: #D34ED5; color:#fff; margin-bottom: 70px; width: 190px;">Sign up</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're getting that error because of this line:

```
<!--<img src="img/sign_up.png" alt="pic">-->
```

You *must* have an `img` tag in your `picture` otherwise nothing will render. If you uncomment that line it should work. Also you have a typo a couple lines above:

```
<source media="(max-with: 480px)" srcset="img/sign_upSmall.png">
```

should be:

```
<source media="(max-width: 480px)" srcset="img/sign_upSmall.png">
```

From the [HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-picture-element):

> The `picture` element content model:
>   Zero or more `<source>` elements, followed by one `<img>` element.

Working snippet below with simple example almost identical to your code above:

```html
<picture>
  <source
    media="(max-width: 480px)"
    srcset="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200"
  >
  <source
    media="(max-width: 768px)"
    srcset="https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400"
  >
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/600x600">
</picture>
```

Above snippet inspected in devtools, clearing showing the smallest image (200x200) and the `source` tag still has 0 width and 0 height:

[image: working picture tag with "source 0x0"]

Comment: Thanks, for responding. I commented out that code because I wanted to see if the small,med images were even registering. Now that I know the <img> tag is needed, I un-commented it. However what is happening is the small, med images are not even used in ipad or mobile devices, its only usin the <img> image. I'll update my post

Comment: @Alexandra you still have a typo in your code. Also, your code is totally fine, I think you're confused because you're seeing "source | 0x0" but your source tags will always have 0 width and 0 height. The source tags never render on the page, they just replace the source of the img element within the picture tag.

Comment: But, when I click on the image in dev tools, it shows the dimensions of the default image. When I highlight the code of the small, med image, it says source 0x0.

Comment: It will always say "source | 0x0" including when it's working. The `source` tags will never ever render on the page. I've updated my answer with a working snippet, please run the working snippet and inspect it in devtools to see for yourself.